# Springdoc extension for AWS API Gatewary

Tags: aws-api-gateway, openapi, springfox, springdoc, springdoc-openui

I want to migrate from springfox 2 to springdoc. Currently, there are multiple plugins (springfox.documentation.spi.service.OperationBuilderPlugin) implemented using the support available in the springfox library.
The plugin of AWS API Gateway is one of them (similar to this one http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#example-operationbuilderplugin).

I didn't found relevant examples or detailed documentation of how I can build something like this using the springdoc support.

Would appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such extension available in springdoc-openapi.

You have an [example with spring-cloud-gateway](https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/02/20/microservices-api-documentation-with-springdoc-openapi/)  that you can adapt.